# read data from a json file using Angular http get

Tags: json, angular, http, get

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:81/{path}/loginResult.json/data')
            .subscribe(result => this.data = result);
            console.log(this.data);
}
```

my loginResult.json

```
{"data":"logged successully"}
```

I try to get corresponding value of data , but I got errors, how to do it correctly

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:81/{path}/loginResult.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the dev server for Angular to proxy your requests while you are developing your application. Doing so will allow you to send requests without CORS errors while you are in the development phase. Here is the documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server